# Sub-carriers spacing in DVB-T2

Tags: digital-communications, ofdm

Looking at DVB-T2 technical specifications I see that sub-carriers spacing has, in the worst case, a value of few hundred hertz, (something like 279 Hz). 32K sub-carriers are used to reach such a low value. I suppose that complex PAPR reduction algorithms plus strong constraints for carrier frequency stability are needed to deal with this number of sub-carriers and frequency spacing. On the other hand, I don't expect that the channel's frequency response would change significantly over few hundreds hertz.

What are the reasons why such a high value of sub-carriers is used?

Answer (score 1):

My best guess: The OFDM modulation scheme in DVB-T2 uses a cyclic prefix. Since we have significant multipath propagation with large delay spreads for television broadcasting, we need a long guard interval to prevent inter-symbol interference. The time duration of this guard interval is pretty much determined by the environment.

If we had a larger subcarrier spacing, the duration of the symbols on each subcarrier would be shorter, but we still need a guard interval of the same length. Therefore, the ratio of (useless) guard interval time to useful symbol time would be quite high, i.e., we'd waste resources. By having lots of subcarriers, the symbol rate on each subcarrier is rather slow, so the duration of the guard interval relative to the useful symbol time is at a reasonable, low level (the ratios for DVB-T2 are 1/128, 1/32, 1/16, 19/256, 1/8, 19/128, and 1/4).